# Why does "appropriate" (and also "duplicate", "deliberate" etc) have a different vowel in their adjective/noun and verb forms?

Tags: etymology, pronunciation, phonology, vowels

#### TL;DR

There are **adjectives/nouns--verb** pairs in which the adjectives/nouns have weak vowel in the last syllable and the verb has strong for example:

- duplicate (adj): /ˈdjuːplɪk**ə**t/
- duplicate (v.): /ˈdjuːplɪk**eɪ**t/

Why?

#### Explanation

There are ***adjective/noun - verb*** pairs that have the same spelling and origin, but the adjectives/nouns have weak vowel in the last syllable, while the verbs have strong. While deliberating the pronunciation of the adjective *deliberate*, I noticed that the verb form and the adjective had different vowels in the last syllable. I don't know if it happens in other words, but the words that I've noticed mostly end in ***-ate***:

| Word | Adj/noun | verb |
| --- | --- | --- |
| deliberate | /dɪˈlɪb(ə)r**ə**t/ | /dɪˈlɪbər**eɪ**t |
| delegate | /ˈdɛlɪɡ**ə**t/ | /ˈdɛlɪɡ**eɪ**t/ |
| appropriate | /əˈprəʊprɪ**ə**t/ | /əˈprəʊprɪ**eɪ**t/ |
| approximate | /əˈprɒksɪm**ə**t/ | /əˈprɒksɪm**eɪ**t/ |
| duplicate | /ˈdjuːplɪk**ə**t/ | /ˈdjuːplɪk**eɪ**t |
| separate | /ˈsɛp(ə)r**ə**t/ | /ˈsɛpər**eɪ**t/ |
| estimate | /ˈɛstɪm**ə**t/ | /ˈɛstɪm**eɪ**t/ |

The above words can be adjectives/nouns or verbs.

I understand that in other noun-verb pairs such as *protest*, the stress varies and the strong/weak vowel is because of that:

- protest (n.): /ˈpr**əʊ**tɛst/
- protest (v.): /pr**ə**ˈtɛst/

But in this case the main stress in both words (adjectives/nouns and verbs) fall on the same syllable, but the last syllable in verb has the diphthong  /**eɪ**/, while the adjectives/nouns have schwa /**ə**/, so the word *appropriate* have two pronunciation in the title sentence:

> Why doesn't "**appropriate**" /ə/ appropriate the pronunciation of "**appropriate**" /eɪ/?

While looking up their etymologies, I found out that most (if not all) of these words entered English in the 15th century. Etymonline doesn't explain why the adjectives/nouns and the verbs have different vowels.

Googling didn't help and I'm unable to find any information on this topic.

Why are these pairs pronounced differently?
What is the origin of this distinction?

Comment: Also: *advoc**a**te, articul**a**te, docum**e**nt*.

Comment: The answer to this question, like almost all questions about English spelling, is that English orthography does not represent Modern English pronunciation. In particular, it does not represent word stress, and therefore not the effects it has on vowel pronunciation. So, basically, there isn't any "why"; speech changed and spelling didn't, so we're stuck with it. Like Windows and capitalism.

Comment: See [Suprafix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suprafix) and [Initial-stress-derived noun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initial-stress-derived_noun) and [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/239164/a-term-for-words-that-change-pronunciation-with-part-of-speech). It's not quite a duplicate question, but it's closely related, and I've no idea if you're asking about *appropriate* or *duplicate* so I'm not going to look up the etymologies of both.

Comment: Related: [Pronunciation of the -ate suffix](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/488902/pronunciation-of-the-ate-suffix)

Comment: @herisson That's loosely related. I wish you could write an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no reference for this, but the evidence seems reasonably convincing. It might be supposed that, as "-ate" is one of the rare suffixes that is not stress neutral (-IC, -ICS, -ATE, -AL, -AN, -OUS, -IVE), and therefore, as it imposes primary stress regularly  on the antepenultimate of three or more syllable words, without distinction of the nature of the word, it was decided that the distinction that can be otherwise introduced by means of early stress and late stress, could be managed through vowel reduction; this appears even more so to be the case from the fact that there is no uniform reduction of the suffix "-ate"for two syllable -ate ending words (this reduction occurring not systematically but rather exceptionally for familiar two syllable -ate ending words (2/ and 3/ below)).

> (LPD, p. 51, -ate) *This suffix is regularly strong,* eɪt, *in verbs, but often weakened  to* ət ɪt *in nouns and adjectives. Its influence on stress depends on the length of the word.
>
> (1) In two syllable verbs stress usually falls on the suffix in BrE* (vi'brate, cre'ate), *but on the stem in AmE* ('vibrate, 'create).
> *(2) In longer verbs, the stress generally falls on the antepenultimate* ('demonstrate, dis'criminate, as'sociate). *There are a few exceptions and cases where speakers disagree* ('sequestrate *or* se'questrate).
> *(3) In nouns and adjectives the suffix is unstressed* ('private, 'climate), *and in longer words the primary stress generally falls two syllables back from the suffix* ('delegate, 'vertebrate, ap'propriate; *important exceptions are* in'nate, or'nate, se'date). *The suffix vowel is generally weak in familiar words* ('climate, 'private), *though in some words speakers vary* ('candidate, 'magistrate). *In more technical words a strong vowel is retained* ('sulphate, 'causate).
> *(4) Note the distinction between verb and noun/adj in cases such as* 'separate, as'sociate, 'moderate, 'delegate.

*Most of the two syllable -ate ending words* ("ət" between parentheses shows an exception to the more usual eɪt pronunciation)

- **1/** **late stress, eɪt**, *only v.*: ablate, collate, cremate, deflate, equate, fixate, formate, gestate, gradate, ligate, locate, migrate, narrate,  negate, notate, nutate, orate, palpate, pulsate, pupate, relate, stagnate, titrate, vacate, vibrate,
  (not a suffix but only an ending: ablate, berate,  cu'rate (eɪt, v.), dilate, instate)
- **2/** **early stress, eɪt**, *no v.*: chordate, curate (ət for the n.), magnate,  prelate (ət), primate (ət (archbishop), eɪt (higher animal)), private (ət), senate (ət),
  (not a suffix but only an ending:  cognate (ət), frigate (ət),  ingrate, oblate, substrate,  template)
- **3/** **early and late stress according to n./a. and v. difference, eɪt**:   castrate,   dictate, frustrate, gyrate (ət for the a.), hydrate, lactate, legate (ət for the n.)
  (not a suffix but only an ending: conflate, donate)

---

---

*Addition made by [user Decapitated Soul](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/567278/why-doesnt-appropriate-adj-appropriate-the-pronunciation-of-appropriate/567286#comment1407509_567286) in the way of providing more information about the suffix "-ate"*

---

Here's what *English Suffixes - Stress-Assignment Properties, Productivity, Selection and Combinatorial Processes* by Ives Trivian says:

This noun suffix (from L[atin] -ātus) rivals -ship in denoting offices or functions and -dom or -hood in naming institutions or collective bodies:
caliphate, cardinalate, catechumenate (< catechumen), collectorate,
consulate, directorate, doctorate, duumvirate (< L <~ duumvir + -ate),
electorate, exarchate (= exarchy), governorate, imamate (< imam), in-
spectorate, etc. (40 items). In the senses defined above, the -ate noun
suffix has been far less productive than its Germanic rivals as it does not
have the capacity to attach to native bases. It is probably no longer alive
as it has not formed any noun since the end of the 19th century.

-ate is occasionally interchangeable with its rival form -ship
in the sense of “position of ” (collectorate/collectorship, pastorate/
pastorship, professorate/professsorship, rectorate/rectorship). In the
foregoing noun class the -ate suffix may additionally denote members
of a function collectively, a sense which -ship does not have: pastor-
ate (s. above + “pastors collectively”); professorate (id. + “professors
collectively”). There is no synonymy in the pairs below:

> (5)
> <sub>consulship (“post of a consul”) ≠ consulate (“residence or workplace of a
> consul”); directorship (“post of a director”) ≠ directorate (“group of people
> directing a corporation”); electorship (“status of an elector”) ≠ electorate (“body
> of electors in a given district”); governorship (“office of a governor”) ≠ governo-
> rate (id. + “an administrative division of a country”); inspectorship (“office of an
> inspector”) ≠ inspectorate (“a body of inspectors”); protectorship (“position of
> a protector”) ≠ protectorate (“state or area controlled by another state”)</sub>

In the meanings defined above, the separable -ate noun suffix is
stress-neutral: 'cardinalate <~ 'cardinal, 'governorate < 'governor,
'mandarinate <~ 'mandarin, 'matriarchate < 'matriarch, 'patriarchate
<~ 'patriarch, 'presbyterate <~ 'presbyter (cp. synchronically transparent or opaque verbs in -ate and their possible homographic nouns or
adjectives, eg. separate, v. and adj., duplicate, v. and n.). In terms of
stress-assignment, opaque-stem nouns in -ate denoting a function, institution, etc., will have to be treated together with -ate verbs: legate
(+ v.), delegate (id.), etc. (§13.3.1).

-ate is also a noun suffix used in chemistry to designate an element of a compound, especially a salt or ester of an acid named by a
noun syngtam with an adjective in -ic (in the same way -ite nouns are
correlative to acids with an adjective in -ous, cf. §10.4): acetate <~
acetic acid, borate <~ boric acid, carbonate <~ carbonic acid, chlorate
<~ chloric acid, hydrate <~ hydric acid, nitrate <~ nitric acid, sulphate
<~ sulphuric acid, etc.

Whereas the foregoing nouns may be analysed as resulting from
affix-substitution between -ic and
-ate, the -ate chemical suffix is always
stress-neutral, as opposed to -ic (car'bonic/'carbonate), although it does
not reduce: ['naɪtr eɪt], etc.

---

*End of addition due to user Decapitated Soul*

---

---

Note that  the stress neutral property of "-ate", as related in the preceding addition, does not take into account the length of the words. In three syllable words stressed on the the second syllable or two syllable words stressed on the first the shift is already effected, so to speak; in many other cases there is a stress shift.

- 'pastorate, di'rectorate, pro'fessorate, e'lectorate, in'spectorate, pro'tectorate, 'doctorate, 'activate, af'fectionate, 'alienate, a'malgamate, etc.
- (*however*) an'tique/'antiquate, a'spire/'aspirate, 'calumny/ca'lumniate, 'certify/cer'tificate, 'college/col'legiate, con'dense/'condensate, de'spair/'desperate, 'difference/diffe'rentiate, di'stil/'distillate, e'xude/'exudate, 'habit/ha'bituate, 'humble/hu'miliate, i'dea/'ideate, etc.

For chemical terms this could be true, but a serious check is needed.

- 'hydrogen/'hydrogenate, 'oxygen/'oxygenate,

Comment: I've added a quote (very long) from English Suffixes - Stress-Assignment Properties, Productivity, Selection and Combinatorial Processes by Ives Trivian with which you could support your answer. The quote below the thick line needs to be formatted and for that purpose, I've added the screenshots from the same pages as the quote. You can see the edit history. :)

Comment: Also edit out extraneous stuff. The paragraphs I copy-pasted are all a quote.

Comment: @Sphinx I am very flattered by your exceptional reward for this little piece of work; it is very kind of you to have  used so many of your personal reputation points that way.  (In spite of the  rather chaotic impression that one gets from the pronunciation of English there are in it rather neat things, and I always thought that this was one of them; perhaps you came to some similar conclusion…)

Comment: Did you ping *me* anywhere? I got a notification for the [above comment](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/567278/why-does-appropriate-and-also-duplicate-deliberate-etc-have-a-different/567286?noredirect=1#comment1409455_567286) and I have no idea why. This is strange because you have pinged the OP not me.

Comment: @DecapitatedSoul No, I didn't; I don't think the software is the best of what could be done. though, it seems that  now and again errors occur (I can't quite think they are due to my computer).